# Qualified dependency injection and coupling

Tags: java, dependency-injection, coupling

Many java DI frameworks (Spring, CDI amongst others) implements some kind of qualified injection through user-designed qualifiers annotations.

```
interface Engine { .. }

@Powerful
public PowerfulEngine implements Engine { .. }

public class Car {
    @Inject @Powerful
    private Engine engine;  // will inject a PowerfulEngine instance
}
```

And this is advertised as a way to enable *loose coupling* between the objects. But because one and only one `@Powerful` implementation will be allowed in the project, I don't understand how this is any less *coupled* than this:

```
public class Car {
    @Inject
    private PowerfulEngine engine;  
}
```

I can see how it would be *vaguely* nicer to mock the interface instead of an 
object when writing an unit test, the fact remains that you specify the exact kind of implementation you need in your injection.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example you are using an `Engine` attribute within your `Car` class. The `Engine` is exposed through an interface and as such you are depending on the interface declaration. Using the annotations you are asking for an implementation of the `Engine` interface named `Powerful`, to let them compiler know which exact implementation of the interface you want to use in this specific case, but the Java compiler still will not allow you to use any method outside the interface's declaration.

**How is the first example less coupled?**

If we consider a scenario where the `PowerfulEngine` only contains methods the `Engine` interface does, meaning the class itself does not add any own methods, the coupling is exactly the same in both cases, however once you start adding specific methods to the `PowerfulEngine` class **and using them** the situation is a whole lot different.

For explanation let's extend your example a little bit:

```
interface Engine
{
    void run();
}

class PowerfulEngine implements Engine
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running a powerful engine.");
    }
}

class RegularEngine implements Engine
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running a regular engine.");
    }
}

class Car
{
    private Engine engine;

    public void go() {
        engine.run();
    }
}
```

The `Car` class has got a `go` method which calls the `run` method of the `Engine`. Now depending on the class that has been injected into a `Car` object the system will either output *Running a powerful engine.* or *Running a regular engine.*

The `Car` class knows it can use the `run` method of the `Engine` because it provides it and does not care about its actual implementation. As I have mentioned, if you decide to replace the `Engine` dependency with the `PowerfulEngine` dependency, in this case nothing happens because you are still using only the method declared in the `Engine` interface.

But if you add another method to the `PowerfulEngine` class and use it, that's a whole lot different case.

Let's modify the `PowerfulEngine` and `Car` classes a little.

```
class PowerfulEngine implements Engine
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running a powerful engine.");
    }

    public void rev() {
        System.out.println("Revving a powerful engine.");
    }
}

class Car
{
    private PowerfulEngine engine;

    public void go() {
        engine.rev();
        engine.run();
    }
}
```

What would now happen if you decided to use a `RegularEngine` instead of the `PowerfulEngine`? Your application would fail during compilation because the `RegularEngine` class does not have the `rev` method, neither does the `Engine` interface. You would be accessing a method which does not exist.

---

All in all, if you are depending on a concrete class and are only using methods available in a certain interface the class implements, it's better to rely on the interface rather than on the class directly, thus letting others explicitly know: *Hey, I am not actually depending on the implementation, I don't care about it, I only care that the interface has these contracts pesented through methods and I can use them.*

If you need to use a specific method of a class which is not published through any abstraction then you have no other option than to rely on a concrete implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you're right, and that's the idea behind these features. 
 I'm still a bit troubled by the concept of 1) making static, prior assumptions 
 of the *exact* type being injected, while 2) *forbidding* the concrete use of its specifics.
 But yes, from a future-proofing point of view, i guess it makes sense.